# Rails 5.1 width Devise gives a 401 using Sendgrid on Heroku when a password is reset

Tags: email, devise, sendgrid, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I'm building a new Rails 5.1 app
Authorization is handled with Devise
I'm using sendgrid for mail delivery
I have made one normal mailer to test my configuration and it's working as expected in both development and production so I assume the email configuration is ok.

When i commit the reset_password form no email is send, from the console i get this

`Started POST "/da/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-06-30 08:32:01 +0200
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"0rR2m6lffy0/eExucO0tv/7Rj1mg6rtEDoL7U6EI4jSwXg8LPoGhPRf+0iVs8Ug3Vu2X+3VNyISzcFjjFHgDAQ==", "user"=>{"email"=>"max@synthmax.dk"}, "commit"=>"Send reset password link", "locale"=>"da"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)`

One thing i noticed is that rails 5.1 mailer inherits from `ApplicationMailer` but devise inherits from `ActionMailer::Base`

I have tried to configure devisie using configure/initializers/devise.rb
`config.parent_mailer = 'ApplicationMailer'`and restart the app without any effect

I have uploaded the project to github https://github.com/maxgronlund/samso

Comment: May be you need to setup `default :from => 'max@example.com'` in your application mailer.

Comment: Not working
Tried and restarted the app, notice! Normal emails send fine. only Devise emails respond with a 401